Micro switch capacitance on the inverting input pin of operational amplifier
I want to use a microswitch on the inverting pin of my transimpedance amplifier to be able to select two different channel of my transducer as follow:

It the microswitch datasheet in is mentioned that there is 10 pF capacitance, I wonder if this capacitance will be in series with the 1 nF capacitance  of the transducer? If yes it can reduce the total capacitance on the inverting pin of the operational amplifier to around 10 pF (considering it will equivalent of 1 nF and 10 pF in series)?

That is not a microswitch but a SMD DIP Switch.
The data sheet says there is 10pF between two closed switches, so that is all you know.
It does not describe how much capacitance there are between each four terminals of two switches you will use.
If such small capacitances matter, you can design the PCB so that there is very little effect from the switch itself, such as choosing the correct input/output terminals and using guard rings or using a grounded switch between the actual sensor terminals.

@ Justme Would you please let me know what do you mean by grounded switch ?

If you have two sensors, use e.g. 4 pin switch and wire the two sensors to switches 1 and 4. Then you can just connect switches 2 and 3 to ground plane and you can either close or open the switches, or you could leave the unused switch pins floating if you need less stray capacitance. It depends why you are worried about capacitance, from signals to ground, or between signals.

@ Justme in fact I have 4 sensors, so I  can not float two of the switches. I worry about the input capacitance on the inverting input of the amplifier, which can cause instability. when the switch is ON we will have 10 pF? or it it is when it is open? in fact when the switch is close there is no capacitance then I can make sure it will work.

@Andromeda Your sensor has capacitance to ground. Your op-amp has capacitor to limit bandwidth. 10pF is 1% of the sensor 1nF. PCB tracks and component pads have multiple pF already. Does 10pF of the switch really have so large effect? Also, how the switch capacitace works is already explained. There will be 10pF between two closed switches, and so nothing is known about any other condition. And everything has some capacitance, so if you worry about 10pF, the assumption that there is no capacitance when switch is closed is wrong as everything has capacitance.

@ Justme Thanks for the nice explanation, would you please let me know if this capacitance of the switch will be in series or parallel with the sensor capacitance? (for the equivalent capacitance which the amplifier sees on the non-inverting input)
